# Polygon background in leaflet

Tags: r, maps, r-leaflet

Is there a way (better in R not to download any additional datasets) how to make polygon (or more visible country borders) in leaflet

Using simple code

```
m = leaflet() %>%
addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
addCircles(lat=15,lng=18, radius = 300, color = "blue")

m
```

Comment: You mean like `addPolygons()`?

Comment: yes, but where can I find polygon data, say for entire Europe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a world sf-dataset in `spData`-package.

```
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
library(spData)

leaflet() %>% 
addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
addPolygons(data = world[world$continent == "Europe",], weight = 1)
```

If you just want the outlines of the countries, use: `addPolylines()`

[image]

Comment: Thank zou very muth I used you advice and rewrite it a bit so the polygons are only around the country  `addPolygons(data = world, col = 'black', fillOpacity = 0.0001, smoothFactor = 0.0001, weight = 2)`